# How to use apispark from CLI

Tags: java, restlet, swagger

How can I introspect an existing restlet server for its resources?

I was starting it like this and ran always into errors:

```
java -cp lib/org.restlet.ext.apispark.jar:lib/org.restlet.jar:dist/myrestapi.jar org.restlet.ext.apispark.Introspector -l swagger -v com.example.service.MyRestService -u xxx -p yyy
```

Do I need to annotate my server resources and how can I achieve it to get my resources and their operations listed?

I also tried to extend `SwaggerApplication` and can at least get a partial result to see my resources but I'd also like to see the methods and would like to annotate my code with the corresponding documentation. How can this be achieved ? How do I have to use swagger annotations with restlet resources?

Answer (score 2):

**Introspection**

You should visit [this page](http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.3/extensions/apispark/introspector.html) to get the right dependencies (some are missing) and syntax.
In your case, I'd try something like this:

```
java -cp lib/*:dist/myrestapi.jar org.restlet.ext.apispark.Introspector -v -u xxx -p yyy com.example.service.MyRestService
```

*Note:* the Introspector is currently under heavy refactoring and you won't be able to upload your definition to APISpark. I'll keep you updated when the service is back in business.

**SwaggerApplication**

The SwaggerApplication will serve the Swagger Resource Listing on /api-docs and the API Declarations on /api-docs/{pathToApiDeclaration}. You should be able to see the methods on the second type of paths.

For an online example, check http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs. The resources dealing with pets are described here: http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs/pet (append the path given in the Resource Listing). The same scheme will be observed by the SwaggerApplication.

There will be support of Swagger annotations in the next version or Restlet as we are currently working on this topic, I'll update this thread once it's done. If it is urgent, you might be interested in looking at the last comments on [this page](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/827).

Hope this helps,